# PHP multiple Queries

Tags: php, mysql

is it not possible to execute both insert and delete on different tables?
or did i missing something

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
    $name= $_POST['edit_name'];
    $name2= $_POST['edit_name2'];
    $pic = $_POST['edit_pic'];
    $contactnumber = $_POST['edit_contact'];
    $address = $_POST['edit_address'];
    $details = $_POST['edit_details'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tabletest (name,name2,pic,contact,address,details,) VALUES ('$name' , '$name2' , '$pic' , '$contactnumber' , '$address' , '$details')";
    $query .= "DELETE FROM tabletest2 WHERE id='$id'";
    if (mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query))
    {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Data Updated";
        header('Location: blankpage.php');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Error, Please try again";
        header('Location: blankpage.php');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You miss a *;* between the statements.

Comment: BTW: learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to perform both DELETE and INSERT but they need to be separate queries. If you want to make both operations atomic (both have to be successful or none of them should be executed) then you need to use [DB transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html).

To execute 2 queries as a single atomic statement you can do the following:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connection = new mysqli();
$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
    $name = $_POST['edit_name'];
    $name2 = $_POST['edit_name2'];
    $pic = $_POST['edit_pic'];
    $contactnumber = $_POST['edit_contact'];
    $address = $_POST['edit_address'];
    $details = $_POST['edit_details'];

    // start transaction
    $connection->begin_transaction();

    try {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO tabletest (name,name2,pic,contact,address,details,) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $name2, $pic, $contactnumber, $address, $details);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM tabletest2 WHERE id=?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
    
        // save data and end transaction
        $connection->commit();

        $_SESSION['success'] = "Data Updated";
        header('Location: blankpage.php');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollback();
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Error, Please try again";
        header('Location: blankpage.php');
    }
}
```